# Can Sphinx Docs support Algolia's Doc Search?

Tags: full-text-search, python-sphinx, algolia

Does anyone know if Algolia's DocSearch Free Service for Docs can be integrated into a Sphinx Documentation Website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can definitely be integrated into a Sphinx-Documentation and that quite easily.

I applied for an account and got the API keys.

Read: https://community.algolia.com/docsearch/run-your-own.html

I installed the free `docsearch-scraper` from github under Python 2.7 and MacOS 10.13 and got it to work using pipenv and an additional post install of the missing dotenv module.

After some fiddling I used a self customized `config.json` based on the output of the `./docsearch bootstrap` command replacing all occurences of "FIXME" in the lines starting with "lvln" with ".section" and replacing "FIXME" in the line starting with "text" with ".document" (see example below).

We successfully indexed the Sphinx-Documentation and running the `.docsearch playground` command opened a test Webserver that delivered instantly excellent results.

We use the readthedocs `sphinx_rtd_theme` and you can add the CSS-Links and Javascript snippets from the algolia docs easily in a `page.html` template extension file created into the `_source/_templates/` folder (see below). This folder may be necessary to be registered in the `conf.py`of your setup!

Add this to your `conf.py` at the existing position:

```
# Add any paths that contain templates here, relative to this directory.
templates_path = ['_templates']
```

and

```
# Add any paths that contain custom static files (such as style sheets) here,
# relative to this directory. They are copied after the builtin static files,
# so a file named "default.css" will overwrite the builtin "default.css".
html_static_path = ['_static']
```

I may come back here with a more detailled step-by-step guide, when I finish the integration.

example config.json:

```
{
  "index_name": "yourindexname",
  "start_urls": [
    "https://replaceme.com"
  ],
  "stop_urls": [
    "https://replaceme.com/omit"
  ],
  "selectors": {
    "lvl0": ".section h1",
    "lvl1": ".section h2",
    "lvl2": ".section h3",
    "lvl3": ".section h4",
    "lvl4": ".section h5",
    "lvl5": ".section h6",
    "text": ".document p, .document li"
  },
}
```

more in: https://community.algolia.com/docsearch/config-file.html

This adds the algolia CSS and a `custom.css` file in the `_source/_static/` folder to override styles. Source of the snippets see https://community.algolia.com/docsearch/dropdown.html

example `page.html` template:

```
{% extends "!page.html" %}

{% set css_files = css_files + ["https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/docsearch.js@2/dist/cdn/docsearch.min.css", "_static/custom.css"] %}

{% block footer %}
<script
src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/docsearch.js@2/dist/cdn/docsearch.min.js"></script>
<script>
docsearch({
  // Your apiKey and indexName will be given to you once
  // we create your config. The appId value is missing in the first 
  // version of this example and in the algolia community doc 
  // until today (5th march of 2019).
  appId: '<your-app-id>',
  apiKey: '<yourkey>',
  indexName: '<yourindex>',
  // Replace inputSelector with a CSS selector
  // matching your search input
  inputSelector: '#rtd-search-form input[type=text]',
  // Set debug to true if you want to inspect the dropdown
  debug: true
});
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

ToDo: Test links to the algolia community documentation

Tipp: You can test if the input selector works by adding this style to your `custom.css` file:

```
#rtd-search-form input[type=text]{
    background-color: #c51919; /* red */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. My approach missed a couple of steps. Once I find some time will get back to it, with your comments and mark it as approved. Thank you!!

Comment: I updated the page.html snippet at the bottom to add the appId to the JSON data. Without it does not work. I can now confirm the this is fully working on a live site for us".

Comment: Quick question. I have done everything you are saying. But I am not able to see the Algolia DocSearch dropdown. Is it because I am on my localhost machine?

Comment: It will also work in a local static build when run from a webserver as long as you have access to the internet. The results are served from the Algolia CDN. For us it works even without webserver. If in doubt use `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`  from the directory _build/html/index.html where the HTML resides.

We had issues with the missing appID value in the page.html snippet above. I mentioned it in the update comment.  Check if you added the line `  appId: '<your-app-id>', ` compared to my initial post. This was doing the trick and was not mentioned in all places of the Algolia docs.

Comment: You need to improve the config.json further to get the content of definition list indexed and omit double indexing of the table of contents: append to ``"text": ".document p, .document li, .document dt, .document dd"`` and add  ``"selectors_exclude": ["[class^='toctree']"],``

Comment: see my Update as seperate Answer below on how to use Algolia Docsearch V3 with a new Sphinx-doc extension.

Answer (score 1):

Update to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54960623/1081006:

**The Algolia Docsearch API was rewritten and now is V3.** There is limited V2 legacy functionality but official support for V2 ended in 2020.

We recently updated the content in our example mentioned above and were not able to get the crawler to run again under Python 2.7 (this is expected due to EOL of Python 2 in 2020).

We could reinstall the crawler using Python3.8 and later 3.11 due to the fact that the latest code was python 3 compatible. https://github.com/algolia/docsearch-scraper.

The crawler could update the indexes at Algolia, but the old v2 Dropdown refused to work now. It generated find results but had no content displayed inside the Dropdown links.

For the Sphinx Frontend we removed our legacy custom integration of the dropdown and switched to the new Sphinx-doc extension `sphinx_docsearch` from https://github.com/algolia/sphinx-docsearch.

The v3 Dropdown now started to work, but the results were not able to address and scroll to the anchors inside the contents. A bad experience similar to the regular Sphinx-doc search.

Origin of the issue was a  switch to HTML5 section markers in the Sphinx-doc HTML that is crawled by Algolia.

We updated the `config.json` file above in the selectors for section by removing the class markup with the dot prefix and switched to HTML5 section markers using the tag name instead to reflect the latest HTML markup in the recent versions of Sphinx and readthedocs theme.

```
  "selectors": {
    "lvl0": "section h1",
    "lvl1": "section h2",
    "lvl2": "section h3",
    "lvl3": "section h4",
    "lvl4": "section h5",
    "lvl5": "section h6",
    "text": ".document p, .document li, .document ol, .document dt, .document dd"
  },
```

If you use a manual generated toctree and get double results with recursion bloating the index add this to your `config.json` at the end:

```
  "selectors_exclude": [
    "[class^='toctree']"
  ],
```

You can watch and test the result at https://userguide.present4d.com/en