# Search "as you type" in sphinx-doc

Tags: full-text-search, python-sphinx

As [mkdocs](https://www.mkdocs.org/) or [mdbook](https://rust-lang.github.io/mdBook/index.html), I want search results are displayed as you type in [sphinx-doc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org) search page.

Is it possible? How to change `_static/searchtools.js`?

Answer (score 0):

User @mzjn contributed in the comments a link to a 3rd party extension that adds *search-as-you-type* to Sphinx, it's the [readthedocs-sphinx-search](https://readthedocs-sphinx-search.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) extension. It's used in the [Read the Docs documentation](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#) and can be tested in the search box there.

Also indicated by @mzjn there's [Algolia search](https://community.algolia.com/) that has [a good example thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54960623) about getting it to work with Sphinx. Here are a couple of example websites where you can see it working: [present4d](https://userguide.present4d.com/en/) and [determined.at](https://docs.determined.ai/latest/index.html).

---

**Sphinx core's search doesn't come with such a functionality.** You can check the Sphinx configurations starting with [`sphinx_search_`...](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_search_language) but all the options are about natural languages and stemming choices (there's also one custom search score option). Next if we check on GitHub the Sphinx project has a dedicated [`html search`](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed+label%3A%22html+search%22) label, but none of the 100 issues mentions a *search-as-you-type* feature. A good place to get an overview of changes to Sphinx's search function is the [Changelog](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/changes.html) with 200 hits for the "search" keyword, however all these issues are also related to stemming, natural languages and scoring search results.

Sphinx's core search has it's own [Web support API](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/changes.html) however there's also no mention of any *search-as-you-type* feature. (As far as I can understand it it's not as simple as just writting some custom Javascript because building a search index also involves using Sphinx core's internal build process.)

Comment: There is https://readthedocs-sphinx-search.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, which is used here: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#

Comment: @mzjn excellent link, thank you!

Comment: It only works on Readthedocs infrastructure: "This extension is developed to be used only on Read the Docs. If you are building your documentation locally, this extension will degrade gracefully...."

Comment: There is also Algolia search. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/54872828/407651. Examples: https://userguide.present4d.com/en/, https://docs.determined.ai/latest/index.html.

Comment: Thanks @mzjn that's great research! I wouldn't have found those solutions without your help!